# PSpice Dependent Source

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, pspice

I'm trying to simulate the above circuit in Pspice, but I am getting the error:

ERROR -- Voltage source and/or inductor loop involving X_F3.VF_F3
You may break the loop by adding a series resistance

[image]

[image]

---

is it possible for power and current values to be zero?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this: -

[image]

Hopefully, that should work.

The gain value for F3 should be 3 and not "F".

You should not short I1.

Comment: I tried it but I still have a problem

Comment: You are still shorting R2 according to the addition in your question @BuseÖzvatan AND you are shorting I1. Neither should you alter your original question to show fixes that are recommended in answers. I have rolled back your question to how it was originally presented. Take note.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working.

Comment: No sorry, I'm a beginner. What is the  next step?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have a question. Powers and currents appear to be equal to zero. Is it true that this happens?

Comment: Please don't change your original question. If you wish to add the new analysis add it and make it clear that the section you are adding is an edit - people reading your question will wonder what I'm answering. So, I'm going to roll it back again. Then, you can add your new analysis that shows powers and currents equal to zero. Please do this properly. I've left a line in your question that shows you where to add edits @BuseÖzvatan

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have shorted through R2, and perhaps you are trying to use a voltage to control the source rather than a current. You also shorted through I1.

Connect the current control terminals of the source in **series** with R2 rather than in parallel.

Comment: thank you very much.